# kdb q shell on linux does not support moving the cursor?

Tags: kdb

In `q` when I try to recall previous command or move cursor, I'm getting printed codes:

```
^[[D^[[C^[[A^[[B
```

IIUC these are the representation of *left, right, up, down* arrows, which are interpretted by shell to do cursor movement, but not in `q`. Is there a way how to have this "functionality" in `q` for linux? What am I doing wrong? As it's not always easy to type without any error from left to rigth, when language itself is evaluated from right to left. Actually it's almost never easy...

Comment: Please take a look at the kx website for installing kdb+ - https://code.kx.com/q/learn/install/#install-rlwrap this will show you how to install rlwrap as Matt Moore suggested which will solve your problem

Comment: you're correct, I overlooked it on that page, sorry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need rlwrap. Set an alias for q. `alias 'q=rlwrap q'`

Edit: realised I messed up the alias syntax

Comment: Nice! Didn't know about this tool. I was afraid I'd have to workaround it using: `while read -ep "q)" R; do echo "$R" | q/l64/q ;done` ;) Thanks!